# How to save/add record from a Excel Form in sheet 1 to excel sheet 2

Tags: excel, vba

Debug error on line - Set myRng = .Range(myCopy)

Unable to understand what is the problem, my data contains filtered data validation list

Without the validation list the data from the required cells is copied perfectly

```
Sub AddGAP()

Dim gapscore As Worksheet
Dim gapdata As Worksheet

Dim nextRow As Long
Dim oCol As Long

Dim myRng As Range
Dim myCopy As String
Dim myCell As Range

'cells to copy from Gapscore Sheet - some contain formulas
myCopy = "A2 ,B2 ,C2 ,D2, ,A6 ,M6 ,N6 ,Q6 ,R6 ,S6 ,T6 ,X6 ,Y6 ,Z6 ,AA6 ,J6 ,L6"

Set gapscore = Worksheets("Gap Analysis Score")
Set gapdata = Worksheets("GAPData")

With gapdata
nextRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
End With

With gapscore
Set myRng = .Range(myCopy)
End With

With gapdata
For Each myCell In myRng.Cells
    oCol = oCol + 1
    gapdata.Cells(nextRow, oCol).Value = myCell.Value
    Next myCell 
 End With
 End Sub
```

**Debug error on line - Set myRng = .Range(myCopy)**

**Error Dialogue - Run time error :1004 - Method 'Range' of Object'_Worksheet' failed**

What should be changed to what value so that the code will run accurately?

Comment: What is the error that you are receiving?

Comment: Run time error :1004 - Method 'Range' of Object'_Worksheet' failed